# Asus AX56 USB dongle finds WiFi networks but refuse to connect

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I have a problem with an Asus AX56 USB WiFi dongle. I've tried connecting to the WiFi from one PC, which works flawlessly, but as soon as I install the dongle in another machine (the machine that will use the dongle permanently) it simply refuse to connect. I can see the SSID's, but as soon as I try connecting it just says "Could not connect to network". It doesn't matter if the network is protected or if it's open, it simply will not connect.

- I've checked all the logs in the router and the dongles MAC address is nowhere to be found.
- I've also tried running Wireshark, but nothing gets registered on the Wireless interface.
- Tried connecting over both 2,4GHz and 5GHz with no luck
- I've tried to uninstall the drivers and downloaded the ones directly from Asus website, still no luck.

Some quick details:

- Network dongle: Asus AX56
- Router: Asus RT-AX92u
- WiFi standard: 802.11ac/ax
- Windows version on client: Windows 11

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Also happens with the Asus AX55 Nano dongle. Tried all the same things as you

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10.
Settings - Network & Internet - Wi-Fi 2 - Hardware properties - MAC

There's a dropdown menu on my Wi-Fi for choosing Wi-Fi or Wi-Fi 2. USB-AX56 is on wifi 2 so it must be selected.

Sometimes it doesn't show up.  Unplugging/re-plugging USB-AX56 remedies this.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).